# Combining several raster tiles of DEM using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic, arctoolbox

I downloaded the DEM data from USGS. It comes with several raster files in .img. 
I know that a mosaic tool can merge them together. I found a lot of tools in the mosaic toolset.

Which one should I use?

Comment: What version of Arc Desktop are you using?

Comment: If you really only have a few rasters then mosaic to new raster should suffice. As you have provide no information about the rasters other than it's file type that's about as good as I can offer...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but you don't want to use the tools in the Mosaic folder. Instead, using ArcToolbox navigate to "Mosaic to New Raster".

Arc Toolbox > Data Management Tools > Raster > Raster Dataset > Mosaic to New Raster

All of the files you are manipulating should have the same cell size because they are all from USGS, but I would double check prior to using the mosaic tool by looking at the properties of each of your layers.